# DateAdd not working in Calculated Query Field

Tags: sql, ms-access, calculated-field, dateadd

I have tried to make a calculated field in a query with the build tool

```
EindDatum: DateAdd("yyyy",1,[tblVERHURING]![DatumVerhuring])
```

I get an error

> The expression you entered contains invalid syntax

If I use the SQL tool and type the following, I get the result I want

```
SELECT DATEADD("yyyy", 1, [tblVERHURING]![DatumVerhuring]) AS EindDatum
FROM tblVerhuring;
```

My question: is it possible to build this SQL expression with the build tool, and what should the code be?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Are you sure `DatumVerhuring` is a `DateTime` column? If it is string, that would explain the error.  ..or if any of your dates are NULL

Comment: I have no problem building that expression in the build tool. If field is Null, expression returns Null. I also tested with a string and Access automatically converts to a date value. An empty string triggers 'datatype mismatch' error.

Comment: Which language of Access are you using?

Comment: I'm using the English version of Access 2019. The field DatumVerhuring is a Date/Time type, no format, no input mask, required = yes, show Data Picker = For Dates.

Comment: I have found out that if I use EindDatum: DateAdd("yyyy","1",[tblVERHURING]![DatumVerhuring]) it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

you probably need to change the `yyyy` for your language.

Maybe this will help you:

```
EindDatum: DateAdd("jjjj",1,[tblVERHURING]![DatumVerhuring])
```

This works for Dutch versions of MS Access

see the related [docs](https://support.microsoft.com/nl-nl/office/dateadd-functie-63befdf6-1ffa-4357-9424-61e8c57afc19)